# Llenar un array [] [] "bidimensional" desde un archivo de texto con elementos separados por comas y renglones

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Pues así como dice el título.

Tengo un .txt con cosas como:

[image: Lista txt].

[Sin las comillas]

Es una lista de 4 elementos por fila, y 150 renglones.

Me imagino agregarlo a un array o arrayList, pero no sé cómo leer el .txt para ir agregando cada elemento a cada índice del array.

Si existe un mejor método para hacerlo [llenar el arreglo] pues bienvenidas sugerencias. También me es posible cambiar la fuente de mis datos, si un txt es muy complicado, o primitivo , o existe alguna mejor manera, adelante, yo elegí un txt porque me imaginé que podría ser más sencillo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es leer el fichero línea por línea y, en cada línea separar por las comas.

Para leer el fichero línea por línea tienes que hacer:

```
public class lee_fichero {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String fichero = args[0];
    String[][] arr = new String[150][4];
    int i=0
    try {
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(fichero);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

      String linea;
      while((linea = br.readLine()) != null){
          System.out.println(linea);  //Aquí tenemos las líneas por separado
          arr[i++]=linea.split(",");

      }
      fr.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Excepcion leyendo fichero "+ fichero + ": " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Si lo quisieras hacer de forma dinámica (si no sabes la cantidad de datos del fichero) tendrías que leer 2 veces el fichero, una para contar líneas y palabras y otro para descomponerlo o hacerlo con listas (ahora lo tendría que pensar un poco más)

Parte de código sacado de: https://blog.openalfa.com/como-leer-un-fichero-de-texto-linea-a-linea-en-java